# Make AJAX call from <a href> click using attribute as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link

```
<a id="container" value="{$variable}" href="#">Click This</a>
```

That I would like to use to POST via an AJAX call.

Here is my code.

```
$('#container').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.post('/cart.php?mode=add&productid={$variablegoes here}&amount=1&redirect_from_cart=Y', function(response){
      alert(response);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy, just read the attribute, encode with `encodeURIComponent`, and concatenate the value into the string.

```
$('#container').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var variable = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post('/cart.php?mode=add&productid=' + encodeURIComponent(variable) + '&amount=1&redirect_from_cart=Y', function(response){
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

The `a` tag does not normally have a `value` attribute however, so I would recommend using a data attribute instead to keep the HTML nice and valid.

```
<a id="container" data-value="{$variable}" href="#">Click This</a>
```

```
$('#container').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var variable = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $.post('/cart.php?mode=add&productid=' + encodeURIComponent(variable) + '&amount=1&redirect_from_cart=Y', function(response){
        alert(response);
    });
});
```